# Filling missing timestamps with NaN in python

Tags: python

I have a dataframe called `ozon`, with only one column called `O3`. It gives mean `O3` values with a timestep of 5 minutes, but unfortunately it's missing some timesteps throughout the dataset. An example:

```
    Datetime           O3       
2020-03-02 10:10:00  20.90
2020-03-02 10:15:00  20.95
2020-03-02 10:20:00  20.53
2020-03-02 10:25:00  20.96
2020-03-02 10:30:00  14.36
2020-03-04 08:00:00  37.77
2020-03-04 08:05:00  33.83
2020-03-04 08:10:00  30.71
2020-03-04 08:15:00  29.83
2020-03-04 08:20:00  29.39
2020-03-04 08:25:00  28.97
2020-03-04 08:30:00  29.03
2020-03-04 08:35:00  29.07
```

You can see almost a gap of two days in the data. I would like to fill these gaps, so that there are no gaps in the 'Datetime' column (so a consistent series with 5 minute timesteps). I'd like the missing `O3` values to become `NaN`. I tried the following piece of code (among others):

```py
ozon.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(ozon.index)
ozon = ozon.reindex(ozon.index, fill_value=0)
```

This unfortunately didn't change anything in the output.
I tried filling the `O3` values with `0`, since I later filter out these values anyway, but the best option would still be to fill with `NaN`.

I've also tried some of the other suggestions I found here on the website, but I unfortunately wasn't able to find a good solution yet. So help is very much appreciated! So thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I've edited my post, I hope it's now right according to the guidelines. I'm quite new at programming (and to this website) so I'm not entirely sure yet whether it's alright now.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `resample()` function. Use:

```
df.set_index('Datetime').resample('5T').sum().replace(0.00, pd.NA) # 5 minute frequency
```

It will add all missing timesteps and fill out `nan` as their values:

```
                    O3
Datetime    
2020-03-02 10:10:00 20.90
2020-03-02 10:15:00 20.95
2020-03-02 10:20:00 20.53
2020-03-02 10:25:00 20.96
2020-03-02 10:30:00 14.36
2020-03-02 10:35:00 NaN
2020-03-02 10:40:00 NaN
2020-03-02 10:45:00 NaN
2020-03-02 10:50:00 NaN
2020-03-02 10:55:00 NaN
....
```

If you do not specifically want `nan` values, just don't `replace()` zeros:

```
df.set_index('Datetime').resample('5T').sum()
```

If datetime is already the index:

```
df.resample('5T').sum()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! However, it does't seem to work, as Datetime is not a column, it's the DatetimeIndex. I can't refer to it with df['Datetime'], so I tried referring to it by: df.set_index(df.index).resample('5T').sum().replace(0.00, pd.NA). I get no error whatsoever, but the DatetimeIndex isn't resampled unfortunately. But thank you very much for the suggestion! I'm a little step further to solving this!

Comment: Then you do not need to reset index just go resampling. I have added that in my answer too